# Dotnet core angular cookie authentication

Tags: angular, .net-core, identityserver4

I am using dotnet core to serve an angular 12 application.
I am also having another dotnet core with identity server 4.
I am also have a dotnet core to handle api requests as a resource server.

Currently angular is using a library for pkce hybrid authentication with identity and retrieve a token for api requests.

I want to change that, so token is not stored on the client. My idea is that angular server will do the code flow authentication with the identity server. Once user is authenticated, tokens, claims etc will be stored on angular server and angular application will be authenticated with a cookie. All client requests will pass through angular server that will inject the token as a proxy to the api.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is what is often called a BFF architecture.

You have an [excellent article from Leastprivilege](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/) on his blog using ProxyKit. Although ProxyKit is no longer a viable project for the future, you can use [YARP](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy) instead.